# How to sign a blackberry application?

Tags: blackberry, sign

I got the signature keys from the blackberry web signer. All the keys in to one folder.

I developed my blackberry application using eclipse plugin 1.0.

First I am go to Blackberry->Install Signatures keys and select the .csi key files but there is nothing happened.

So I double click the key values and register the keys. Register keys successfully.

Then copied the three key values in component package bin folder. Then go to eclipse plugin blackberry and select the request signatures. Nothing happened.

How to sign my application? Please do help me for sign the application.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the "How_And_When_To_Sign_V2.pdf" attachment on this website:
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/How-and-When-to-Sign/ta-p/442779